# Trying to make audio visualization with circle ripples on Canvas and with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

Basically I'm trying to make an audio visualization with circle ripple explosions. I am not sure how to exactly name it, but it looks something like this: https://codepen.io/alek/pen/EyyLgp, except I'm looking for more like when you click a circle appears, expands and disappear. It doesn't necessarily have to be a filled circle.

Here's my js code for audio visualization (Note: I did take the code from Nick Jones - website: https://codepen.io/nfj525/pen/rVBaab, and I credit him for the cool audio visualizations made)

```
let file = document.querySelector("choose-file");
let audio = document.querySelector("audio-player");

file.onchange = function() {
  let files = this.files;
  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
  let context = new AudioContext();
  let src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  let analyser = context.createAnalyser();

  let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  src.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);

  analyser.fftSize = 256;

  let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  console.log(bufferLength);

  let dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

  let WIDTH = canvas.width;
  let HEIGHT = canvas.height;

  let barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
  let barHeight;
  let x = 0;

  function renderFrame() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

    x = 0;

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
      barHeight = dataArray[i];

      let r = barHeight + (25 * (i/bufferLength));
      let g = 250 * (i/bufferLength);
      let b = 50;

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
      ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

      x += barWidth + 1;
    }
  }

  audio.play();
  renderFrame();
};
```

So currently this audio visualization is creating rectangles according to the music, but I would like to change that to circles instead. So on the canvas, circles would appear randomly on the screen and have this ripple, explosion effect, disappear and a new circle would appear. I thought maybe I could replace `fillRect()` with `arc()`, but I realize that there is more logic behind it. Does anybody have any ideas how I could possibly change the rectangles to circles?

Answer (score 0):

usually i'm using p5.js, i think p5.js preety good for something like that, just a suggestion if you want to use that, this the link : https://p5js.org/libraries/